# For $x\in E$ and $x = x_1 + x_2$, where $x_1 \in E_1$, shouldn't the distance vector of x from the subspace $E_1$ be unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality, direct-sum, direct-product

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algebra* by Werner Greub, at pages $194 - 195$, it is given that

> If $E_1$ is a subspace of n-dimensional inner product space $E$, and
> $E_1^\perp \subseteq E$ is the orthogonal complement of $E_1$ in $E$,
> then since  $$dim(E_1) + dim(E_1^\perp) = dim (E)$$, and  [image]

But in the problems following this page, it is asked that

> Given an inner product space $E$ and a subspace $E_1$ of finite
> dimension, consider the decomposition
>
> $$x = x_1 + x_2 \qquad x_1 \in E_1$$ and the projection
> $$x = p+h \qquad p\in E_1, h\in E_1^\perp$$ Prove that
>
> $$|x_2| \geq |h|$$

But since $E = E_1 \oplus E_1^\perp$, shouldn't the decomposition

$$x = x_1 + x_2 \qquad x_1\in E_1, x_2 \in E_1^\perp$$
be unique ? And hence $p = x_1 $ and $h = x_2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $3$-space, let $E_1$ be the $x$-axis, 
$$
x = (3, 1, 2) = x_1 + x_2 = (1, 0, 0) + (2, 1, 2)
$$
Then $x_1$ is in $E_1$ as required, but $x_2$ is not perpendicular to it. The $p+h$ decomposition is 
$$
x = p + h = (3, 0,0) + (0, 1, 2)
$$
by the way.

Note that $\|(2, 1, 2) \| \ge \|(0, 1, 2) \|$ as claimed.

Comment: $x_2 $ cannot have  x-component since $x_2 \in E_1^\perp$

Comment: Look at the problem as written. Nowhere does it say that $x_2 \in E_1^\perp$. You were, perhaps, over-assuming.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: You're welcome.